# BASH Variable substitution(?)

Tags: .bash-profile

I have the following script:

```
var1="var1value"
var2="var2value"
var3="var3value"
```

I want to create the following code:

```
option=$1

myvar=`echo var$option`
```

So, when the option is "1" the myvar should be var1value, when the option is "2" the myvar should be "var2value" etc.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
myvar=$(eval echo \$var$option)
```

However, `eval` is a risky instruction so you'd rather use an array instead of this kind of variable naming, eg:

```
var[1]="var1value"
var[2]="var2value"
var[3]="var3value"

option=$1

myvar=${var[$option]}
```